# Android Notifications not display the message body

Tags: android, delphi, google-cloud-messaging

I am writing my own message provider to send out push notifications on both iOS and Android.  I have the provider working well for iOS.  My problem is Android.  With the app not running, The phone gets the message and notifies the user a message came in.  I only see the icon in the message.  The message body is not displayed.  If the app is running, the app gets the message event and I can see in the JSON, the message body and message title.  So it would appear that the information is coming through.  I've tried this on an Android running JellyBean and Marshmallow and get the same results.  I also tried using Googles test notification from their web site for FCM.  I get the same results with their web notification send.  Any ideas?

Here is the code I am using in Delphi:

```
HttpClient.Request.URL := 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

HttpClient.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
HttpClient.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: key = ***'); // Server Key from Google
HttpClient.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';

JSONMsg := TJSONObject.Create;
JSONMsg.AddPair('to', devicetoken);

JSONInfo := TJSONObject.Create;
JSONInfo.AddPair('body', edtMessage.Text);
JSONInfo.AddPair('title', 'CODY Mobility');
JSONInfo.AddPair('priority', 'high');
JSONTrue := TJsonTrue.Create;
JSONFalse := TJsonFalse.Create;
JSONInfo.AddPair('content_available', JSONTrue);
JSONInfo.AddPair('dry_run', JSONFalse);

JSONToSend := TStringStream.Create(JSONMsg.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);

StatusMemo.Lines.Add('Sending Android message to device: ' + deviceToken);
try
    HttpClient.Post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', JSONToSend);
except
    on E:Exception do begin
        StatusMemo.Lines.Add('Message send failed: ' + E.Message);
    end;
end;

StatusMemo.Lines.Add('Android message response: ' + HttpClient.ResponseText);
FreeAndNil(JSONTrue);
FreeAndNil(JSONFalse);
```

Comment: Have you tried sending a [`data`](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)-*only* message payload for Android? With this, it is sure that your app should be the one to handle the notification, not the System Tray.

Comment: Yes, I did try just sending a data only payload but that did not solve my problem.  I want to be able to send and display messages to the phone, when the app is not running.  When the app is running, the app gets all the information in the payload, data or notification, which the app can then display without problems.

Comment: Hi Joe. So you mean to say that your app is able to receive messages in both foreground and background and that you just want to receive messages even when your app is closed or killed. Is that right?

Comment: Correct.  When the app is closed, I want Android OS to display the message text.  All it displays is the app icon for the notification.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem! It appears to be a bug with Delphi. My original message sent was:

```
{"to":<MyDeviceID>","notification":{"body":"It finally works!!!!!","title":"CODY Mobility Title","priority":"high","content_available":false,"dry_run":false}}
```

If I change my message to the following, it now works:

```
{"to":"<MyDeviceID>","data":{"message":"It finally works!!!!!","title":"CODY Mobility Title","priority":"high","content_available":false,"dry_run":false}}
```

I had to change from "notification" to "Data" and I had to change the "body" element to a "message" element. With those changes in place, the phone gets and displays the message when the app is closed. Of course, this no longer matches Google's specs for sending a notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging. I dug into the Delphi code and I found a Delphi java script called NotificationPublisher.Java. In there, there is code which specifically looks for a message element.

```
 if (jsonVal != null) {
if (jsonVal.has("message"))
{ msg = jsonVal.optString("message"); }

else if (jsonVal.has("msg"))
{ msg = jsonVal.optString("msg"); }

else if (jsonVal.has("alert"))
{ msg = jsonVal.optString("alert"); }

if (jsonVal.has("title"))
{ title = jsonVal.optString("title"); }

}
} else {
// Look for msg or message in bundle
if (key.equals("message"))
{ msg = valstr; } else if (key.equals("msg")) { msg = valstr; }

if (key.equals("title"))
{ title = valstr; }
}
```

I am not sure where Delphi checks for Notification elements versus Data elements. But I believe this is part of the problem. I created a support ticket so Embarcadero can look into this further. If anyone else has this problem... Just change your message and it'll work.